# SQL SERVER 2016 is using lot of resources. almost 4GM RAM without any cause

Tags: sql-server-2016

[My Task Manager Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb0xw.png)

If I restart service then it starts with 4% of RAM, then gradually increases

Comment: 4GB for a SQL instance is nothing... Especially considering that the minimum RAM that the host must have is 2GB. Unless you have defined the the maximum RAM for the instance it can use up 95% of the hosts RAM, or the limit of the version/edition of SQL Server you are using; which ever is lower. For example, a SQL Server 2012 Standard installation on a host with 128GB of RAM will happily use about 122GB of RAM.

Comment: [Server memory configuration options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/server-memory-server-configuration-options?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I have set max server memory. now.